# disable WordPress sidebar widgets with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I want to be able to remove the added widgets in my `WordPress` site

through `functions.php` like making the site clean without any plugins.

I found this code

```
// Delete All Existing Widgets
$sidebar_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
foreach($sidebar_widgets['footer_first'] as $i => $widget) {
    unset($sidebars_widgets['footer_first'][$i]);
}
wp_set_sidebars_widgets($sidebars_widgets);
```

but it doesn't seem right to work.

I searched and searched all over the internet but all I got is how to `unRegister` the whole widget which I'm already familiar with.

and I only want to remove it from the sidebar section.

Comment: have you know the name of `sidebar` like in the above example `footer_first`? please check with inspect element you can see the exact name of the sidebar widget

Comment: yes it's `footer_first`

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code hope for hiding sidebar**

```
function disable_sidebar_custom( $sidebars_data )
{
   if($sidebars_data['footer_first'] !=''){
        $sidebars_data['footer_first'] = false;
   }          
   return $sidebars_data;
}
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'disable_sidebar_custom' );
```

Comment: this is working well but the only problem i need the code to be inside another function .. so how would that be possible ?

Comment: you just need to put above code inside `function.php` that's it

Comment: no i meant i already have a function which is importing some demo and my idea was delete existing data on wordpress and making it clean before importing so i know nesting functions won't work is there any possible to do this code inside a functions which runs after clicking import ? and thanks a lot for your help